# Persist values in spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-analytics

I am using the [Google Analytics Spreadsheet add-on](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on)  to fetch report data into a spreadsheet. The data from Google Analytics is pulled daily in my spreadsheet and shown in an Overview sheet. However, I would like to store the values for later reference.

[Google Analytics add-on sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T4zN8apJLnNxC-7yUqlmdnJ6JMJb5YxZtysY6EQ4Grw/edit?usp=sharing)

[image: Sample]

My idea is to store all daily values in one sheet and fetch these values via `INDEX`/`MATCH`.

I would like to "persist" the row of the current day after the Google Analytics report is run, to store this value for the future.

Any suggestions how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Google Analytics Spreadsheet Add-on](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on) **doesn't have an `append` feature, so you cannot keep data from previous runs and add data from new runs**.

**However, you don't need to**: since you're going to do a lookup (`index-match`), it doesn't matter on which rows the data sits, since you're lookup is going to find it. So you can build your reports to get data from the last N days (eg last year with `Start Date = TODAY()-366` and `End Date = TODAY()-1` (not getting data from today due to GA data processing latency). Traditionally when doing reporting you're interested in a time period that's relative to now (eg "how has it been going for the last 12 months?"), hence the above method would be suitable.

**If you want an `append` feature, you need to use other solutions**, like [SuperMetrics](https://supermetrics.com/?idev_id=1265).